# How to use spelling suggestion (related query) with Dynamic Result Cluster (GSA)?

Tags: google-search-appliance

We use the Result format (from the Search Protocol) for our results page (we manually parse the XML responds). We wishes now to switch to the Dynamic Result Clusters format.  The only problem is that spelling suggestion (Related Queries) doesn't seem to be available using that protocol.

The only solution I seem to find is to:

1. First do a `/clusters...` request. If the request return no result...
2. ...to another request to `/search...` to see if that request would return a spelling suggestion (Related Queries).

Am I missing something? Can the Clusters format return also spelling suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

`/clusters` request are not to be use instead of the `/search` request.

You must :

1. First, do a normal `/search` request.
2. Then, do a AJAX request to `/clusters` to produce the suggestion.

So you keep all the features of the `/search` request (KeyMatches, Related Queries, etc).